# Using jQuery, how can I pull data from a JSON file and cycle through content using prev and next clicks?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, json

I'm trying to create a feature using jQuery that displays content from a JSON file anytime the user clicks on the prev and next links (arrows). For example, when a user lands on the page, the first JSON object is displayed by default. When the user clicks the "Next" arrow, it displays the next object from the JSON file. After clicking the fourth time, the user would be returned to the first JSON object. No matter how populated the JSON file is, the user will only see four JSON objects.

Currently, the page includes JavaScript, which I inherited, and has hardcoded divs for each of the four views. I'm trying to configure it so that all the data is pulled from an external JSON file. The first part of the script is jQuery and is successfully fetching the JSON file. For the new version of the page, I wouldn't mind using jQuery for consistency.

I have a loadData() function in the jQuery right now, which I used to test my connection to the JSON file. That test was successful and I've since removed the loadData button. Once I figure out how to cycle through the first four objects in the JSON file, I'll be able to complete the HTML and CSS.

Thanks for any input.

```
  <div class="container-fluid welcome-bar">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-12 welcome-bar-content">
        <div class="greeting">Welcome!</div>
        <div data-tabs-navigation="#issue-nav"></div>
        <div><a href="" class="btn-welcome att-track">Subscribe now</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container featured-issues">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="issue-label">
          <h1>Featuring: Theme name lorem ipsum</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="issue-nav" class="css-pages">
          <div class="row featured-issues-wrapper">
            <div class="col-sm-6 featured-issues-content" style="display: flex; flex-direction:column; max-width:662 px;">
              <div class="article-display-title" style="display:flex;">
                <h3>Theme featured article title lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="article-descriptive-text">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam..</p>
              </div>
              <p class="article-date-time">Month xx, 20xx | x min read</p>
              <p class="article-link-text">
                <a href="">Read the post</a>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 featured-issues-image">
              <img src="https://www.leonardodavincischool.org/sites/main/files/imagecache/medium/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg?1576635745" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p>Page 2 Ipsum - This div is redundant and needs to be deleted.</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p>Page 3 Dolor - This is another redundant div which needs to be removed.</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p>Page 4 Test - This is the last object.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("#example").DataTable();

    // Data source for testing
    var testDataUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/loganatsea/features/main/issues"

    $("#loadData").click(function() {
      loadData();
    });

    function loadData() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: testDataUrl,
        contentType: "text/plain",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          myJsonData = data;
          populateDataTable(myJsonData);
        },
        error: function(e) {
          console.log("There was an error with your request...");
          console.log("error: " + JSON.stringify(e));
        }
      });
    }

    // populate the data table with JSON data
    function populateDataTable(data) {
      console.log("populating data table...");
      // clear the table before populating it with more data
      $("#example").DataTable().clear();
      var length = Object.keys(data.issues).length;
      for (var i = 1; i < length + 1; i++) {
        var issue = data.issues['issue' + i];

        // You could also use an ajax property on the data table initialization
        $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData([
          issue.issue_number,
          issue.issue_label,
          issue.issue_link,
          issue.issue_link_cta,
          issue.display_description,
          issue.featured_image,
          issue.publish_date,
          issue.time_to_read
        ]);
      }
    }
  })();
});

const products = document.getElementById("articleList");
class issueCatalog {
  async issueItems() {
    try {
      let result = await fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/loganatsea/features/main/issues");
      let data = await result.json();
      // return data

      /* destructuring data */
      let issueList = data.issueList;
      issueList = issueList.map((item) => {
        const issueKey = issueList.issueKey;
        const issueDate = issueList.issueDate;
        const issueEdition = issueList.issueEdition;
        return {
          issueKey,
          issueDate,
          issueEdition
        };
      });
      return issueList;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}

/* Display stuff from the basket */
class Display {
  displayIssues(issueCatalog) {
    //console.log(issueCatalog)
    let result = "";
    issueCatalog.forEach((item) => {
      result += `
        <li>
        issueKey : ${issueList.issueKey}
        issueDate: ${issueList.issueDate}
        issueEdition: ${issueList.issueEdition}
        </li>
        `;
    });
    articleList.innerHTML = result;
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const issueCatalog = new issueCatalog();
  const display = new Display();

  issueCatalog
    .issueItems()
    .then((issueCatalog) => display.displayIssues(issueCatalog));
});

class issueNav {
  constructor(selector, options = {}) {
    Object.assign(
      this, {
        EL: document.querySelector(selector),
        page: 0,
        selector,
        btnPrev: {},
        btnNext: {},
        issueDate: {},
        classActive: "is-active",
        onChange: () => {}
      },
      options
    );
    this.EL_pages = this.EL.children;
    this.EL_navigation = document.querySelectorAll(
      `[data-tabs-navigation="${this.selector}"]`
    );
    this.total = this.EL_pages.length;
    this.EL_prev = this._ELNew("button", {
      type: "button",
      textContent: "<",
      onclick: () => this.prev(),
      ...this.btnPrev
    });
    this.EL_issue = this._ELNew("span", {
      type: "span",
      textContent: `Issue: ${this.page}`
    });
    this.EL_next = this._ELNew("button", {
      type: "button",
      textContent: ">",
      onclick: () => this.next(),
      ...this.btnNext
    });
    this.EL_buttons = Array.from(Array(this.total)).reduce((arr, _, i) => {
      const EL_btn = this._ELNew("button", {});
      arr.push(EL_btn);
      return arr;
    }, []);
    this._init();
  }

  // Utility function - New element
  _ELNew = (sel, attr) =>
    Object.assign(document.createElement(sel), attr || {});

  // Fix negative modulo index
  _mod = (n) => ((n % this.total) + this.total) % this.total;

  // Initialize
  _init() {
    // Append nav buttons to DOM
    this.EL_navigation.forEach((EL) =>
      EL.append(this.EL_prev, this.EL_issue, this.EL_next)
    );

    // Set current page
    this._page = this.page;
  }

  prev(n = 1) {
    this._page -= n;
    return this;
  }

  next(n = 1) {
    this._page += n;
    return this;
  }

  show(idx) {
    this._page = idx;
    return this;
  }

  set _page(n) {
    this.page = this._mod(n);
    [...this.EL_pages, ...this.EL_buttons].forEach((EL) =>
      EL.classList.remove(this.classActive)
    );
    [this.EL_pages[this.page], this.EL_buttons[this.page]].forEach((EL) =>
      EL.classList.add(this.classActive)
    );
    // Provide a callback
    this.onChange.call(this);
  }

  get _page() {
    return this.page;
  }
}

// Use like:
const mySectionTabs = new issueNav("#issue-nav", {
  onChange() {
    console.clear();
    console.log(`issueKey: ${this.page}`);
  }
});
```

JSFiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/Codewalker/vmas2bzq/5/

Answer (score 3):

So based on your question, it seems you are stuck on

> Once I figure out how to cycle through the first four objects in the
> JSON file, I'll be able to complete the HTML and CSS.

Since there's a lot going on in your example, here's a simplified version to show the concept on how you can rotate between cards:

The variable `issuesToLoopOn` at the top lets you pick how many issues you want to loop on , no matter the length of the issues array.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/shaunakv1/4k2ufmvn/125/

HTML

```
<button id="previous">previous</button>
<button id="next">next</button>

<div id="card">
  <div id="issue_number"></div>
  <div id="issue_label"></div>
  <div id="issue_link"></div>
  <div id="issue_link_cta"></div>
  <div id="display_description"></div>
  <div id="featured_image"></div>
  <div id="publish_date"></div>
  <div id="time_to_read"></div>  
</div>
```

JS

```js
let issues;
const issuesToLoopOn = 3;

$(document).ready(async function () {
    const res = await fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/loganatsea/features/main/issues');

    const json = await res.json();
    issues = Object.values(json.issues);

    //display first issue by default
    displayJson(issues[0]);
    //write current displayed index to dom ( optionally you can save in a state variable)
    $("#card").data('idx', 0)
    $("#card").data('total', issues.length);
});

$("#next").on('click', () => updateNextCard(1))
$("#previous").on('click', () => updateNextCard(-1))


function updateNextCard(by) {
    let currentIdx = parseInt($("#card").data('idx'));
    let nextIdx = currentIdx + by;

    if (nextIdx === issuesToLoopOn) nextIdx = 0;
    else if (nextIdx < 0) nextIdx = issuesToLoopOn - 1;

    console.log(nextIdx); //update dom and state

    displayJson(issues[nextIdx]);
    $("#card").data('idx', nextIdx);
}

function displayJson(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        $(`#${key}`).html(`<p><b> ${key} </b>: ${obj[key]} </p>`);
    });
}
```

> Update
> I have updated the answer to show how to use values from JSON and show it on DOM. You don't really have to "parse" JSON in JavaScript. You can simply use it as an Object or an Array. JSON literally stands for JavaScript Object Notation.  In your case you can "spread around" the div's where ever in the HTML. As long as they have the right ID that is referenced by jquery selector this will work.

Here's the updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/shaunakv1/4k2ufmvn/157/

Comment: Thank you for the post. This looks great. How would I go about parsing out a single field from the JSON file? For example, next to the word Issue in the blue nav bar, I need to include the "issue_number", then in the body, I need to display JSON objects in different divs.

Comment: @linnse I have updated the answer and another fiddle to show what you asked for. You can just use the individual keys from json to show values. I am just iterating on them for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks for the updated fiddle. It doesn't do anything when I click prev/next.

Comment: Are you sure? it's working fine for me